# Enabling dropdown buttons with Zurb Foundation 5 - using sass mixins

Tags: javascript, html, sass, zurb-foundation, mixins

I want to add a dropdown button to my website using Sass mixins. I've read the docs on Javascript and followed the installation to the best of my knowledge and I've gone through the docs on Dropdown Buttons. Here is my html:

```
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop" class="login">Dropdown Button</a><br>
<ul id="drop" data-dropdown-content class="f-dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is my scss:

```
 .login {
  @include grid-column(2);
  @include button();
  @include dropdown-button();
}
```

Here my javascript installation: (at the end of my html file before the closing body tag except modernizr which is at the top of my html file)

```
<!-- modernizr -->
<script src="/js/custom.modernizr.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- automatically loads the Foundation Core and all JavaScript plugins. -->
<script src="/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Foundation -->
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

The only resuly I get with this code is a foundation styled button, but when you click it there is no dropdown options. Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this issue for a simple dropdown button.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Before you can use dropdowns you'll want to verify that both jQuery (or Zepto) and foundation.js are available on your page. You can refer to the javascript documentation on setting that up. [Foundation Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html)

Comment: Please create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the compiled CSS

Comment: Here is my compiled CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/MattCamp/TLX8Q/

Comment: @AlexGuerrero Did that help solve the issue? I still need help. Also I have jquery and javascript installed. I just can't get the dropdown working. See my question here for updated code: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/843-

Comment: @AlexGuerrero sorry about the duplicate questions. I took care of it. Thanks for pointing it out. Edited answer is above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include all required js files. From [Foundation Docs](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html#configure-with-javascript):

> Make sure `jquery.js` `foundation.js` and `foundation.dropdown.js` have been included on your page before continuing. For example, add the following before the closing `<body>` tag:

```
 <!-- ... -->

<!-- your button... -->
<a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" class="button">Dropdown Button</a><br>
<ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown">
  <li><a href="#">This is a link</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">This is another</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Yet another</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- ... -->

<!--
Here you should include the paths of your javascript files and initialize foundation
Add all these scripts before the closing <body> tag
-->

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Foundation -->
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<!-- Foundation dropdown -->
<script src="js/foundation.dropdown.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize Foundation -->
<script>
$(document).foundation();
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: I already have the jQuery, Foundation, Foundation dropdown, and intialize foundation in my code, and it still doesn't work. What do you mean by "Here you should include the paths of your javascript files and initialize foundation
Add all these scripts before the closing <body> tag" ?

Comment: Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLX8Q/3/), it includes your compiled CSS and works. What jQuery version are you using?

Comment: I don't understand why it is not working on my site. Did you add any thing to the css?

Comment: No, I used your css only. check if your script paths match with your js files

Comment: I have the same code that you posted in your answer. Any ideas why mine is not working? (I am using: MAMP Pro, Mac OSX Mavericks, Google Chrome, Zurb Foundation 5 with Sass mixins, and compiling using compass)

Comment: Try to use the CDNs of the JSFiddle to test if it works

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by CDNs?

Comment: There is a [post](http://robertgreiner.com/2011/05/using-a-content-delivery-network-to-host-jquery/) explaining what is a CDN. Replace your js paths by the CDN urls that I used in my JSFiddle.

Comment: I think that it must be a problem of you script versions or files

Comment: Will it cause any problems using the CDNs?

Comment: I'd just like to add that a lot of the focus seems to be on ensuring that the Javascript is added correctly. In my case, I resolved the issue by ensuring that all CSS files were available. I was using a compiled version of Foundation's CSS, and I found that when I switched to the full CSS of Foundation (from Bower), the dropdown worked correctly.